# Detect Listview last row on scrolling - Android

Tags: android

I want to load data in listview when it is displaying last row. I am writing scroll event for listview.

Now how to detect that listview is displaying last row?

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 5):

```
        lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // Check if the last view is visible
            if (++firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount > totalItemCount) {

                // if so, download more content

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Amazing ListView](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/) to have auto-loading of next pages (i.e. "Loading..." on the last item).

[image: ListView with "Loading..." animation at the bottom]

As per the documentation implement these methods:

> - `onNextPageRequested` Called when user scrolls the list until the    "loading" indicator is visible. This is called on UI thread, so if you
>     have some network requests, make sure you do it on the background. The
>     page number is also given.
>
> By default, you are considered to be in the last page, and you will
>   not see any "Loading..." message on the bottom of the list. You need
>   to control whether there are still pages to be displayed.
>
> - `notifyMayHaveMorePages` to indicate that we still have more data,    hence "Loading..." message will be shown.
> - `notifyNoMorePages` to indicate that we have loaded all the data, hence no more "Loading..." message to be shown.
> - `nextPage` to increase the page number. Do this when you append new data into your adapter.
> - `resetPage` to reset the page number to 1 (or to the value specified by `setInitialPage`).

So what you need to do is fetch more data when **`onNextPageRequested`** is called. And call **`nextPage`** when you append new data into your adapter.

Comment: Yes i am looking for this. I am trying it. And will inform you

Comment: Hi I tried that demo. Its very useful. I need to add items dynamically as the listview is scrolled. The items in listview are added like this: I am parsing one api. It will return 5 items and added in ListView. When ListView ands it will again call api and return next 5 items. How can I do this? Can you please show me some code for this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in list view.. it wrks fine with me..

```
((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollDowns)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above implementaion by slezadav may cause errors at edge conditions. The sum of first visible item & items in page may be 1 count more or less than expected. I was using the same thing untill i switched to a new method.
 What i did was put a listener to the Adapter of listview and in the getview check          if(position== totalItemCount of items in array to be displayed), 
if yes i call up my listener from adapter and the listener will Pull more data from api. Quite simple